# STL decomposition of time series with missing values for anomaly detection

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, na, stl-decomposition

I am trying to detect anomalous values in a time series of climatic data with some missing observations. Searching the web I found many available approaches. Of those, stl decomposition seems appealing, in the sense of removing trend and seasonal components and studying the remainder. Reading [STL: A Seasonal-Trend Decomposition Procedure Based on Loess](http://www.wessa.net/download/stl.pdf), stl appears to be flexible in determining the settings for assigning variability, unaffected by outliers and possible to apply despite missing values. However, trying to apply it in R, with four years of observations and defining all the parameters according to http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/stl.html , I encounter error:

> time series contains internal NAs

when `na.action = na.omit`, and

> series is not periodic or has less than two periods

when `na.action = na.exclude`.

I have double checked that the frequency is correctly defined. I have seen relevant questions in blogs, but didn't find any suggestion that could solve this. Is it not possible to apply stl in a series with missing values? I am very reluctant to interpolate them, as I do not want to be introducing (and consequently detecting...) artifacts. For the same reason, I do not know how advisable it would be to use ARIMA approaches instead (and if missing values would still be a problem).

Please share if you know a way to apply stl in a series with missing values, or if you believe my choices are methodologically not sound, or if you have any better suggestion. I am quite new in the field and overwhelmed by the heaps of (seemingly...) relevant information.

Comment: How many missing values do you have? You could try the `na.approx` function from the `zoo` package to interpolate your missing data.

Comment: Some extra thoughts: apparently, now the package `stlplus` can handle missing values in ts decomposition. `Rbeast` may be another alternative; it is a Bayesian algorithm, Unlike `stl` that only decomposes time series, Rbeast does time series decomposition and changepoint detection at the same time, with missing values allowed. Here is an example:  `library(Rbeast)`;  `co2[ sample(1:length(co2), 200) ]=NA`;  `plot(beast(co2))`.

Answer (score 22):

In the beginning of `stl` we [find](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/stl.R)

```
x <- na.action(as.ts(x))
```

and soon after that

```
period <- frequency(x)
if (period < 2 || n <= 2 * period) 
    stop("series is not periodic or has less than two periods")
```

That is, `stl` expects `x` to be `ts` object after `na.action(as.ts(x))` (otherwise `period == 1`). Let us check `na.omit` and `na.exclude` first.

Clearly, at the end of `getAnywhere("na.omit.ts")` we find

```
if (any(is.na(object))) 
    stop("time series contains internal NAs")
```

which is straightforward and nothing can be done (`na.omit` does not exclude `NAs` from `ts` objects). Now `getAnywhere("na.exclude.default")` excludes `NA` observations, but returns an object of class `exclude`:

```
    attr(omit, "class") <- "exclude"
```

and this is a different situation. As mentioned above, `stl` expects `na.action(as.ts(x))` to be `ts`, but `na.exclude(as.ts(x))` is of class `exclude`.

Hence if one is satisfied with `NAs` exclusion then e.g.

```
nottem[3] <- NA
frequency(nottem)
# [1] 12
na.new <- function(x) ts(na.exclude(x), frequency = 12)
stl(nottem, na.action = na.new, s.window = "per")
```

works. In general, `stl` does not work with `NA` values (i.e. with `na.action = na.pass`), it crashes deeper in Fortran (see full source code [here](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/stl.f)):

```
z <- .Fortran(C_stl, ...
```

Alternatives to `na.new` are not delightful:

- `na.contaguous` - finds the longest consecutive stretch of non-missing values in a time series object.
- `na.approx`, `na.locf` from `zoo` or some other interpolation function.
- Not sure about this one, but another one Fortran implementation can be found for Python [here](http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/browser/trunk/Lib/sandbox/pyloess?rev=2844). One could use Python of possibly install R from source after some modifications, in case this module really allows missing values.

As we can see in the [paper](http://cs.wellesley.edu/~cs315/Papers/stl%20statistical%20model.pdf), there is no some simple procedure for missing values (like approximating them in the very beginning) which could be applied to the time series before calling `stl`. So considering the fact that [original implementation](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/stl.f) is quite lengthy I would think about some other alternatives than whole new implementation.

**Update:** a quite optimal in many aspects choice when having `NAs` could be `na.approx` from `zoo`, so let us check its performance, i.e. compare results of `stl` with full data set and results when having some number of `NAs`, using `na.approx`. I am using [MAPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) as a measure of accuracy, but only for trend, because seasonal component and remainder crosses zero and it would distort the result. Positions for `NAs` are chosen at random.

```
library(zoo)
library(plyr)
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
mape <- function(f, x) colMeans(abs(1 - f / x) * 100)

stlCheck <- function(data, p = 3, ...){
  set.seed(20130201)
  pos <- lapply(3^(0:p), function(x) sample(1:length(data), x))
  datasetsNA <- lapply(pos, function(x) {data[x] <- NA; data})
  original <- data.frame(stl(data, ...)$time.series, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  original$id <- "Original"
  datasetsNA <- lapply(datasetsNA, function(x) 
    data.frame(stl(x, na.action = na.approx, ...)$time.series, 
               id = paste(sum(is.na(x)), "NAs"), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  stlAll <- rbind.fill(c(list(original), datasetsNA))
  stlAll$Date <- time(data)
  stlAll <- melt(stlAll, id.var = c("id", "Date"))
  results <- data.frame(trend = sapply(lapply(datasetsNA, '[', i = "trend"), mape, original[, "trend"]))
  results$id <- paste(3^(0:p), "NAs")
  results <- melt(results, id.var = "id")
  results$x <- min(stlAll$Date) + diff(range(stlAll$Date)) / 4
  results$y <- min(original[, "trend"]) + diff(range(original[, "trend"])) / (4 * p) * (0:p)
  results$value <- round(results$value, 2)
  ggplot(stlAll, aes(x = Date, y = value, colour = id, group = id)) + geom_line() + 
    facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y") + theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(), strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) + 
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
    lapply(unique(results$id), function(z)
      geom_text(data = results, colour = "black", size = 3,
                aes(x = x, y = y, label = paste0("MAPE (", id, "): ", value, "%"))))
}
```

`nottem`, 240 observations

```
stlCheck(nottem, s.window = 4, t.window = 50, t.jump = 1)
```

[image]

`co2`, 468 observations

```
stlCheck(log(co2), s.window = 21)
```

[image]

`mdeaths`, 72 observations

```
stlCheck(mdeaths, s.window = "per")
```

[image]

Visually we do see some differences in trend in cases 1 and 3. But these differences are pretty small in 1 and also satisfactory in 3 considering sample size (72).

Comment: Right, it seems the implementation of `stl` in R is based on the Fortran implementation discussed in Section 4 (page 20) of the paper linked in the question, which eschews design goal 4 (page 5) in favor of speed (see bottom of page 21).  I was hoping for a solution that does allow for missing values (an implementation of which apparently exists for S).  Although I suspect that in most cases the differences between passing input through `na.approx` before `stl` wouldn't differ too greatly from an implementation of stl that handles missing values, and that is indeed my fallback option.

Comment: @user1935457, I updated my answer. Clearly the implementation of `stl` in R lacks some parts, but as I mentioned in my answer, it might not be worth rewriting it, especially if it really would not differ much as you said. Just thought about some tests with full data and with `na.approx`, I will update my answer with results..

Answer (score 9):

Realize this is an old question, but thought I'd update since there is a newer `stl` package available in R called `stlplus`. [Here is its homepage on github](https://github.com/hafen/stlplus). You can install it from CRAN with `install.packages("stlplus")` or directly from github with `devtools::install_github("hafen/stlplus")`.