# seasonal decomposition on non-uniform spaced time series, any well-established algo in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, time-series, statsmodels, stl-decomposition

stats package in R has stl(), but it requires a uniformly spaced time series created by ts(). It can't deal with zoo objects.

Strangely, it can't deal with missing values either, although STL method claims to be able to fill in missing value with LOESS. (see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/stl-on-time-series-with-missing-values-for-anomaly-detection) on CV.)

So for example, if you have business day data, you can't just make it calendar day by putting NA on weekends and call stl().

I also see the author of Python statsmodel trying to migrate stl() to work with Pandas TimeSeries, but it doesn't seem to be there yet.

Thanks

Edit: Just to add that I know I can just do a very simple model like fitting harmonics, but I want a well-established model to at least provide benchmark. I have sub monthly data, so X12 is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

According to @Julius in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14616460/2824732) is it possible to use `stl` with `na.approx`, from `zoo` package, using `stl(x, na.action = na.approx, ...)`. This does some sort of [interpolation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/na.approx).

Unfortunately `stl` prefers regular time series.

So I take @Julius approach to test how well `loess` performs in filling `NAs` assuming a irregular time series. Apparently the error is very small.

## Lets simulate

The following function takes the data and simulate scenarios with `3^(0:p)` NAs with `naapprox=TRUE` for using `na.approx` and `optspan=TRUE` to optimize span parameter. The loss function is MAPE.

```
#The approach is based in @Julius stl with NAs
library(zoo)
library(plyr)
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
mape <- function(f, x) colMeans(abs(1 - f / x) * 100,na.rm=T)

loessCheck <- function(data,p=2, naapprox=TRUE, optspan=TRUE){
  set.seed(20130201)
  pos <- lapply(3^(0:p), function(x) sample(1:length(data), x))
  datasetsNA <- lapply(pos, function(x) {data[x] <- NA; data})
  original <- data.frame(y.predict=as.numeric(data))
  original$id <- "Original"
  datasetsNA <- lapply(datasetsNA, function(y){ 
    posna=which(is.na(y)) 
    tvo=1:length(y) 
    yo=y;tv=tvo
    if (any(posna%in%c(1,length(y)))) tv=tvo[-posna[which(posna%in%c(1,length(y)))]]
    if(naapprox) y=na.approx(y) #instead of inside loess
    if(optspan){ fseq=function(x, y)
      mape(matrix(predict(loess(y ~ dt, span=x, data.frame(dt=tv, y=y))),ncol=1),as.vector(y[!is.na(y)]))
    ospan <- optimize(fseq, c(0.1,1), maximum=FALSE,y=y)
    spanmim <- ospan$minimum
    } else spanmim <- 0.75
    y.loess <- loess(y ~ dt, span=spanmim, data.frame(dt=tv, y=y))
    y.predict <- predict(y.loess, data.frame(dt=tvo))
    y.predict[-posna] <- yo[-posna]
    data.frame(y.predict, 
               id = paste(length(posna), "NAs"), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    })
  loessAll <- rbind.fill(c(list(original), datasetsNA))
  loessAll$Date <- time(data)
  results <- data.frame(y.predict = sapply(lapply(datasetsNA, '[', i = "y.predict"), mape, original[, "y.predict"]))
  results$id <- unique(loessAll$id[-(1:nrow(original))])
  results <- melt(results, id.var = "id")
  results$x <- min(loessAll$Date) + diff(range(loessAll$Date)) / 4
  results$y <- min(original[, "y.predict"],na.rm=T) + diff(range(original[, "y.predict"],na.rm=T)) / (4 * p) * (0:p)
  results$value <- round(results$value, 2)
  ggplot(loessAll, aes(x = Date, y = y.predict, colour = id, group = id)) + geom_line() + 
     theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(), strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) + 
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
    lapply(unique(results$id), function(z)
      geom_text(data = results, colour = "black", size = 3,
                aes(x = x, y = y, label = paste0("MAPE (", id, "): ", value, "%"))))
}
args(loessCheck) # first boolean for using na.approx, the second for optimize span parameter in sample


loessCheck(nottem,p=3) #T T
```

[image]

```
loessCheck(nottem,p=3,FALSE) #FT
```

[image]

```
loessCheck(nottem,p=3,FALSE,FALSE)
```

[image]
    loessCheck(nottem,p=3,TRUE,FALSE)
[image]

Less MAPE when using `na.approx` from zoo package and recommended `span= 0.75`. After filling the NAs other modelling alternatives may be considered.