# Time series in R stl-decomposition

Tags: r

I am a new user of time series analysis in R. My data structure is as follows:

```
Date                     Amount

15/05/2010             2
16/05/2010             9
17/05/2010             11
18/05/2010             4
19/05/2010             0
...                     ...
```

That means, my data is on a daily basis, but some values are missing.

How can I do a "stl"-decomposition in R with that kind of data?

Thanks in advance, Uli.

Comment: I think this could help with na http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058390/stl-decomposition-of-time-series-with-missing-values-for-anomaly-detection